# How to get full path of a window in Windows Explorer

Tags: c++, c

When I have to open a folder in `Windows Explorer` (for example `d:\myfolder\test`), I use `::GetForegroundWindow()` to get its `Window Handle`, and use `::GetWindowText` to get the Title Text. But in the default windows the full path of the current window is not displayed (of course you can through `tools-folder option-view-display full path` in title bar to set the title bar to display full path), and the `::GetWindowText` only gets `test`. If I want to get the full path `d:\myfolder\test` how can I get this by the windows handle got by `::GetForegroundWindow()` ?

Any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the [ShellWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM object.  See [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx) on how the get the folder that an Explorer window is viewing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will explorer it latter.